# Squashing more patches into one single patch

Tags: git

I would like to know which is the correct/best way of merging more patches into one single patch when using git. In particular I can have it working doing this:

```
git am --signoff my_first.patch
git am --signoff my_second.patch
git format-patch master --stdout > first_plus_second.patch
```

I am not expert of git, but it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's interesting - why do you want have a single patch?

I think better solution is to make a branch from the master, then use merge --squash
then commit the squashed changes and format-patch. In this case it looks like all merges will go smoothly and it looks better in the history.

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b your_branch_squashed
git merge --squash your_branch
git commit -m "my changes squashed"
git format-patch master
```